# jquery load localhost page onclick

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have this page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("asdf");
var url = "http://localhost/test/test.php";
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $('body').load( url );
});
});
</script></head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button" value="click" />
</body>
</html>
```

i want to load the content of the url and put it in the body, but nothing happend , why please? how to solve ?

Comment: Where is your jQuery include?

Comment: Is the page containing this located on localhost? If not, cross-domain AJAX prevents this from working.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the JS console?

Comment: in the same directory with test.php, but i didn't include it, have i ? if yes how pelase?

Comment: errors in browser console should be first step to troubleshoot... `$ is not defined` or similar error text will be thrown giving you the first clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you including jQuery anywhere in that document, which you need to do in order to use the object's properties and methods.

To include your jquery script in your document, you simply add it as a script line to your head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourscriptpathgoeshere.js"></script>
```

Take note that it must go before any of the scripts that use jquery.. it cannot go after the script, for instance.

The below code, as an example, works fine for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var url = "http://localhost/testing/test.php";
            $("#button").on("click", function() {
                $('body').load( url );
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="click" />
    </body>
</html>
```

To get the href of a specific link.. provided the html is valid(and only one item has the id 'link'), use the following method:  [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), in the following manner:

```
var href = $("#link").attr('href');
```

Comment: it works, please stil just one thing, i have this `<a  id="link" href="http://www.totti.com">click</a>` in the page i want to load, how to get the href value ? i want the href value not all the page , pelase help

Comment: please heleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeep